# User details only appear after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, user-interface, authentication

The following is my code for displaying the user's name and mail id when they login through a social media account:

.ts

```js
constructor(private router: Router, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 

this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user != null) {
    // User is logged in, use the user object for its info.
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.user_displayName = user.displayName;
      this.user_email = user.email;
      console.log("Logged in");
      console.log(user);
      this.router.navigate(['']);

  } else {
    // User is not logged in, redirect to where you need to.
      console.log("Logged out");
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
      this.user_displayName = '';
      this.user_email = '';
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
});
}
```

.html

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
  <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Logged In: {{user_displayName}} ({{user_email}})<p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
  <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Logged Out</p>
</div>
```

Now once the page shows up after logging in, I need to refresh that page to see the user details. If I do not refresh the page, it keeps showing Logged Out. Only after refreshing the page do the details show up.

Any way I can show the details right after I login? Without refreshing the page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might have to give some info about this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged.Havent used firebase.Your issue sounds like you are trying to call the function before the view is initialised.Try moving the code from constructor to ngOnInit() and console.log the data and get back to me please

Comment: @vikk The same thing is happening. Having to refresh.

Comment: any resource you can redirect me to quickly understand how onAuthStateChanged works?

Comment: @vikk Actually I myself got it by asking questions on stackoverflow. The tutorial I had followed used an older version of AngularFire2.

Comment: anything would do.I just want to know if it does an async call

Comment: @vikk Maybe you can check my previous questions to get an idea [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647804/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-auth] and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668119/has-no-exported-member-injectiontoken]

Comment: console.log the "user" variable.See if you are getting the data properly

Comment: instead of `this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(` can you try using `his.afAuth.authState.subscribe(` . Please find this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/comment) log into comments by using fb or google this is what you want i guess

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks! Changing it to subscribe worked!